# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\test2\server\app.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

im working with node but i just get the following error in the console:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\test2\server\app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

and this is my json:

```
{
  "name": "check-in ",
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "watch": "nodemon app.js"


  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "sequelize": "^6.30.0"
  }
}
```

I'm just trying to make the server work but nothing seems to work

Comment: Provide your file directory structure in `test2` plz

Comment: https://files.fm/u/97g23g4dh

Comment: Where exactly is your `test2` folder?

Comment: test2 is the root folder

Comment: your `app.js` is under `/server/src`, not under `/server`, you may need this `"start": "node src/app.js"`

Answer (score 2):

Your `package.json` should be in the same location as your `app.js`. (as you use `node app.js`). So make sure they are in the same location and it should work.

If they already are together and you still encounter the problem, try to move the project somewhere else since being in OneDrive can cause some problems with the paths depending on your permissions.

EDIT:
Ideally is to have the main module (`app.js`) in the root level of the project. So if your project is `test2` your `app.js` should be:
`C:\Users\User\OneDrive\test2\app.js`

And your package.json:
`C:\Users\User\OneDrive\test2\package.json`